# How do I disable messages or logging from printing on the console/virtual terminals?

Tags: log, console, syslog, virtual-console

My wireless driver is noisy.  It prints out messages to the console every 10-30 seconds.  So, if I'm working on VT1 or something, I get messages scrolling by all the time.  Is there a way to shut this feature off?  I like working on the virtual terminals, but this is making it hard to deal with. :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use the command

```
sudo dmesg -n 1
```

to suppress all messages from the kernel (and its drivers) except panic messages from appearing on the console.

To fix at each boot, add the command to:

```
/etc/rc.local
```

Answer (score 51):

`dmesg` comes with two handy options for that:

```
-D, --console-off           disable printing messages to console
-E, --console-on            enable printing messages to console
```

`dmesg -D` is just a shortcut for `dmesg -n 1`, except that it stores the current log level, so that you can easily restore it with `dmesg -E`. So it's a bit more convenient than changing the log level with `dmesg -n`.

Additionally, you can check the current log level with:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7       4       1       7
```

`man klogctl` for more explanations on these numbers...

Comment: Note that `dmesg -D` and `dmesg -E` have subsequently been broken by [capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) (q.v. CAP_SYSLOG there).  However, setting `kernel.dmesg_restrict=0` **does not** enable these two `dmesg`s; so far, I have found no way to enable them for Ubuntus after the time that the [`kernel.dmesg_restrict=1` default was instituted](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2020-June/041063.html).

Answer (score 10):

**`/proc/sys/kernel/printk`**

You can also set the log level directly with

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

which is basically what `dmesg` is doing.

The format of that file is explained at: https://superuser.com/a/793692/128124

**`loglevel` command line boot parameter**

Sets the initial value at boot time, which allows you to see pre-init messages.

Comment: Hey hey, I tested myself by not reading your answer 1st and I nailed it \o/ that said can this be done with ‘sysctl’?