# Messages from syslogd flooding the terminal when waking up from sleep

Tags: tmux

So, after browsing the web for a few days and without finding any solution to my problem, I thought I had to expose it here to seek one, as nothing has worked so far.

I am using Tmux, and I see these message appearing on every session, attached or not, after waking the laptop up from sleep:

```
Message from syslogd@parrot at Mar 28 23:17:54 ...
 kernel:[177769.535034] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: ee0000000040110a

Message from syslogd@parrot at Mar 28 23:17:54 ...
 kernel:[177769.535035] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef82240 MISC 78a0000086

Message from syslogd@parrot at Mar 28 23:17:54 ...
 kernel:[177769.535040] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:40651 TIME 1553811472 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 24

Message from syslogd@parrot at Mar 28 23:17:54 ...
 kernel:[177769.535044] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ee0000000040110a

Message from syslogd@parrot at Mar 28 23:17:54 ...
 kernel:[177769.535044] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef82300 MISC 78a0000086

Message from syslogd@parrot at Mar 28 23:17:54 ...
 kernel:[177769.535048] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:40651 TIME 1553811472 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 24
```

This does not happen with a terminal that is not running Tmux, so I first though it was due to Tmux, but it doesn't appear to be.

I've tried `dmesg -1`, `dmesg -D`, changing the values of kernel.printk in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reloading sysctl, and even putting 0 1 0 0 there did not change a thing.

I've read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97256/how-do-i-disable-messages-or-logging-from-printing-on-the-console-virtual-termin), [that](https://serverfault.com/questions/776330/disabling-syslogd-messages#776333), and so far nothing changed this behavior. I do find these messages in my `/var/log/kern.log`, but not at the same times, and I don't understand why these specific ones go to Tmux.

One of the guys at the Tmux github said this, but it didn't help so far:

> It sounds like syslogd has decided that it should send these messages to a terminal rather than a file and that a pty inside tmux is the best place to send them.

I am at a loss of ideas, so I'd be grateful for pointers as to what that might be caused by! It's becoming really annoying as all of my sessions are flooded and it's even worse when vim is open.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: That is a bug in microcode from Intel. https://askubuntu.com/questions/928390/kernel-outputting-this-should-i-worry-hardware-error-processor-0406e3-ti  seems to have some tips and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1467040 and please do not cross post with our sister site https://superuser.com/questions/1420031/messages-from-syslogd-flooding-the-terminal-when-waking-up-from-sleep

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll have a look, and sorry for multi-posting, I didn't know which site was the most appropriate.